# Let $ABCD$ be a cyclic quadrilateral and let $AB$ and $CD$ meet at $E$. Let $M= (EBC)\cap (EAD)$. Prove that $OM\perp EM$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a cyclic quadrilateral and let $AB$ and $CD$ meet at $E$. Let $M= (EBC)\cap (EAD)$. Prove that $OM\perp EM$

I took midpoint of $AB$ as $M_1$ and midpoint of $DC$ as $M_2$ . I noticed that $(EM_1OM_2)$ is cyclic and it is enough to show that $EM_1OM_2M$ is cyclic.

[image]

PS: Diagram by @Shubhangi

Comment: Could you attach afigure. also explain the mean  of M=(EBC)n(EAD)

Comment: @sirous a figure: https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/zm94j6n8

Comment: @Raheel shall I add a diagram ? you can edit it if you want ..

Answer (score 1):

You are very close!

[image]

Just note that M is the spiral center of the spiral similarity $S$ sending $AB$ to $DC$ .
And hence the spiral similarity $S$ also take the midpoint of $AB$ to midpoint of $DC$.

So $S:M_1 \rightarrow M_2 $

So $S:BM_1 \rightarrow CM_2$ .

So $M$ is the spiral center of the spiral symmetry which takes $BM_1$ to $CM_2$.

But notice that $BM_1\cap  CM_2=E \implies M =(EBC) \cap (EM_1M_2)$

So $M \in  (EM_1M_2)$ and by your observation, we get $M\in  (EM_1OM_2)$ , and hence we have $OM\perp EM$.

---

Here M is called the miquel point and if we  define $F=BC\cap DA$ , then we have $M\in EF$ if $ABCD$ is cyclic .

Comment: oh.. yeah! I got it.. took me some time to understand though...